# Users added to Firebase Authentication but not to RealTime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to be able to register users into my database.
After I register the users they are being added to my firebase authentication which is great but nothing is changed in my Realtime Database.
It's worth mentioning that my Firebase location isn't in the US.
I have tried many different things:

1. Put the firebase link inide of the "getInstance()"
2. Replace the current google-services file with an updated one, including the Firebase's link inside of it
3. use getReferenceFromUrl() with the firebase's link inside of it.

None of those seemed to work.

Main part of the code in which I'm trying to register the user:

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(name, email, password);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                    }
                });
```

These are the Realtime Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

It's worth noting that I have tried everything I found, including an answer to the same question in this site. Unfortunately none seem to work for me so I had to ask to understand the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed? Is any of the onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo Nope. The only toast that is working is when it fails to register a user. When it does register a user it just exists the activity without any toast.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: use `addOnFailureListener()` to display the error that occurs to the user.